arrange recyclerview items in a "relaxed" way, not a specific amount of items per row
I'm trying to create a recyclerview that shows items in a non-specific way.
For now I've only managed to use StaggeredGridLayoutManager to allow different lengths of items but they're still shown in 2 rows.
what ive achieved till now:
spanCount = 2
spanCount = 1
I'm trying to achieve something between them, no specific set of rows, just fit as many as possible in a row.
I tried to look for other LayoutManagers and didn't find anything that fits what I'm looking for

can you post desired code?
